# Spring Boot: Altering database tables at runtime

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Currently developing a web application using Spring Boot where a user is expected to upload .CSV files with contacts to populate the database.

- Each .CSV file (contacts list) may have a different set of columns (Such as: Name, Email, Address, etc..).
- Each list may contain thousands of records.
- The application involves reading and writing each of the lists individually.
- The app also must provide for insertion/deletion of columns.

**Question 1**: what is the best approach to insert such data to the database?

So far I could think of two options:

Having a single table which will contain all the data from all of the lists.
[image: Having a single table which will contain all the data from all of the lists.]

OR

Create a new table for every new list.
[image: Create a new table for every new list.]

**Question 2**: Whilst the first option is easy to implement using Spring Boot's JPA + Hibernate, I'm not sure how to approach the second one. Since the fields are different from list to list, we cannot provide a resource representation class. Any suggestions?

**Question 3**: Having resource representation classes and using Hibernate is it even possible to dynamically alter database tables (insertion/deletion of columns)?

Comment: For give good feedback, write create table. image not enough helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use **MongoDB** as your database because it saves data in *JSON* format, record fields can be ***different*** from each other, so maybe in your case it is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very small CSV files, you will run into problems using MongoDB. It has a 16 MB limit on the size of JSON documents, which means that around 6 MB worth of CSV data you will reach it. Even if your files are smaller, it is still inefficient to store tabular data in JSON. Even with MongoDB's compression the size of your data will increase by a factor of 2-3.

For a relational database I think your best bet is to write custom DDL code to create / alter / drop tables on the fly. I am myself somewhat surprised that there seems to be no library for this.

Another idea might perhaps be to use a Key Value Store. But I don't have enough hands-on experience with that to give a concrete recommendation.